Provide data to blade in laravel
How can I efficiently pass data from two different controllers to the same blade page simultaneously in Laravel?
While working on my Laravel application, I encountered an issue where the blade page seems to only fetch data from one controller, disregarding the other controller. Despite attempting various solutions, I couldn't resolve this problem. How can I ensure that the blade page retrieves data from both controllers as intended

You need to use AJAX or similar to make calls to other controllers once the first controller has returned a rendered page to the browser. Or you need to combine the output of all the controllers and finally render the blade file in one controller which was originally called by the client

Thank you, Tony, for your suggestion. I appreciate your input and will certainly give it a try.

You can't do this natively but you have a few options to achieve what you need to.
Services
You can extract the functionality inside of these components and put them into a service or services. This allows you to maintain seperation of concerns and not repeat implementations inside your application.
The Laravel documentation doesn't have any details on services themselves but they do cover Service Providers and Services are used inside the framework its self.
Larvel Daily has an excellent article that covers moving logic from controllers to services Laravel Controller into Service Class
Ajax
You could make a controller that renders the data that both controllers provide by using Javascript to retrieve the data via AJAX. This would mean converting your current controllers to work as an API endpoint and not return a view but just the data required.
I wouldn't recommend this as it's more difficult than it needs to be and the extra complexity isn't providing you with any tangible benefits. If the majority of your application is not structured like this it can be confusing when it doesn't fit the pattern you've created.
Livewire
I prefer to leverage Livewire in situations like this as it allows me to register and render child components inside my main component. Livewire also provides a ton of other benefits that can allow your application to feel more modern without adding a lot of extra complexity or introducing more languages / frameworks.
Components are very similar to controllers as it contains some logic and a view, this could be a good option for you as it'll do what you need to do and isn't a steep learning curve.
Blade Components
Blade also has Blade Components. This works very similar to Livewire in that you have a component with a class file that implements any logic. It's not too different to how a controller works which is again similar to Livewire.
This means you could move the controller logic into these Blade Component's Classes.
In your situation this is the most suitable solution given the requirements and problems you've set out in your question. You don't need to install any extra packages, Learn another framework or any other language.
However, Livewire may be better for you depending on how you want to solve your problems.
In my opinion I like to use blade components for components that will be rendered multiple times throughout my application such as a button that may show an icon or change size and what it does when clicked that all can be flexible to configuration via arguments it accepts.
Then I use Livewire for heavier things that don't get repeated throughout my application and that does enough to warrant the usage of a component.
This makes my project structure clearer as I know where to find components that have a decent amount of logic behind them and are for certain features / areas of my application.
The blade components that are found inside the App\View\Components namespace are then just used for components that are used commonly throughout my application.

Thank you, Dylan Marriott , for your suggestion. I appreciate your input and will certainly give it a try.

It's no problem, I forgot to add View Components so I've just added the details fro them in now @Nadir
